# Set div height relative to UIWebView frame.size

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uiwebview

I want to have the height of my div be

I have a UIWebView inside a subclassed UITableViewCell. Inside that UIWebView I have some basic html with one div.

```
_editorHTML = [@"<html>"
               "<head>"
               "<style>"
               ".contentContainer { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:1em; }"
               "</style>"
               "</head>"
               "<body>"
               "<div id=\"content\" contenteditable=\"true\" style=\"height:100%;\" class=\"contentContainer\">%@</div>"
               "</body>"
               "</html>" retain];

[_webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:_editorHTML, @""] baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:directory]];
```

Is there a way to have the height of the div be the height of the UIWebView? When I set height:100%, it only makes the div be about a quarter of the height of the UIWebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight"]` will give you the height of your content (do it after the html finishes loading, eg in `webViewDidFinishLoad`). Also, since you are doing this in a tableview, you'll have handle the fact that the cell's size has changed.

Slight caveat, if your webview is already taller than the height of the internal content, it will actually return the height of your web view.